# Virtual Host Naming in Ubuntu

Tags: apache2

Can you include a forward slash (/) in the "server name" for a virtual host in Ubuntu Server9.*?

I'm trying to redirect a website such as mysite.mydomain.com to mydomain.com/mysite.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, hostnames can't contain slashes. Try something like this:

```
# This assumes NameVirtualHost *:80 at some earlier point in your config

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mysite.mydomain.com
  RedirectPermanent / http://mydomain.com/mysite/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mydomain.com
  # DocumentRoot etc as usual
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Woops, hit return.  The users need to be able to type mydomain.com/mysite into the browser and maintain that illusion although pointing to the host set up for mysite.mydomain.com